# QML StackView: Item Destroyed on pop

Tags: qml

Consider the following example:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 320

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        Component.onCompleted: {
            stackView.push( { item: comp1, destroyOnPop:false } )
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: comp1
        Rectangle {
            color: "lightgray"

            Text {
                id: mtext
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "First Page"
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: comp2
        Rectangle {
            color: "lightgreen"

            Text {
                id: mtext
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Second Page"
            }

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: mtext.text += " Clicked"
            }
        }
    }

    Row {
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        Button {
            id: next
            text: "Next"
            onClicked: {
                stackView.push( { item: comp2, destroyOnPop:false } )
                enabled = false
                prev.enabled = true
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: prev
            text: "Prev"
            enabled: false
            onClicked: {
                stackView.pop()
                enabled = false
                next.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm pushing 2 `Component`s into the `StackView` on the each button clicks, i.e. clicking the "Next" button loads the second page. When I click on it, it displays an updated text("Second Page Clicked"). Then clicking "Prev" loads the first page as expected.

Now if I click "Next" again, it should load the second page with that updated text ("Second Page Clicked"), but it doesn't. It shows the initial text ("Second Page").

So the question is whether the `Item` is destroyed on pop? If not then shouldn't the second page display the updated text ("Second Page Clicked")?

I have even set the flag `destroyOnPop` to `false`. Have I misunderstood the concept of `StackView`? Any possible way to solve this?

I want to load any page from any point in `StackView` and that the state of `Item` be as it is where I left it. Just like `QStackWidget`, where we use `setCurrentIndex()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation is referring to `Item` object whereas you are using `Component`s. The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#details) is pretty clear about the fact that a component is **not** an `Item` since it is not derived from `Item`. Indeed a `Component` act like a `Class` which is instanced to a specific object.

Each time you call

```
stackView.push( { item: comp2, destroyOnPop:false } )
```

a new "instance" of the component `comp2` is generated and such *new* instance is used instead of the previous one. I strongly suggest to read [this article](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) to better understand the correlation between `Component` objects and generated instances.

Instances can be generated via `createObject` function. Hence, you can create an array of `Item`s and use such `Item`s instead of the `Component`s. Final code looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 320

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        Component.onCompleted: {
            push( { item: items[0], destroyOnPop:false })
        }
        property variant items: [comp1.createObject(), comp2.createObject()]  // objects from the components
    }

    Component {
        id: comp1
        Rectangle {
            color: "lightgray"

            Text {
                id: mtext
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "First Page"
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: comp2
        Rectangle {
            color: "lightgreen"

            Text {
                id: mtext
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Second Page"
            }

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: mtext.text += " Clicked"
            }
        }
    }

    Row {
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        Button {
            id: next
            text: "Next"
            onClicked: {
                stackView.push({ item: stackView.items[1], destroyOnPop:false })
                enabled = false
                prev.enabled = true
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: prev
            text: "Prev"
            enabled: false
            onClicked: {
                stackView.pop()
                enabled = false
                next.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The same correct result could be achieved by defining directly the `Rectagle` objects in the source. In this case we have two `Item`s which are reparented to the `Window` thanks the `destroyOnPop` set to false.

```
Rectangle {
    id: comp1
    color: "lightgray"
    visible: false

    Text {
        id: mtext
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "First Page"
    }
}

Rectangle {
   id: comp2
   color: "lightgreen"
   visible: false

   Text {
        id: mtext2
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Second Page"
   }

   MouseArea {
       id: mouseArea
       anchors.fill: parent
       onClicked: mtext2.text += " Clicked"
   }
}
```

Comment: In second case the Rectangle will be loaded directly instead of loading into the StackView which is why I considered the Component. But didn't considered that Component is not an Item. It's clear now :)