# QML: StackView and replace

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, qml, qt5

I'm not sure to use `StackView` correctly.
I have several QML objects and I show them replacing the currentItem in the `StackView`. This is an easy way to have transitions without use two `Loaders`.

Something like:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

StackView {
    id: stack
    anchors.fill: parent
    initialItem: initObj
}

Component {
    id: initObj
    ModuleHome {}
}

Component {
    id: obj1
    Module1 {}
}

// ...

stack.push({item: item, replace: true, destroyOnPop: true})
```

It happened I had a bug in one page and I noticed the error messages in the debug console were repeated as many times as I pushed the object.

I.e.
First time:

> qrc:/MyObject.qml:15: TypeError: Cannot write property of null

Second time:

> qrc:/MyObject.qml:15: TypeError: Cannot write property of null
>
> qrc:/MyObject.qml:15: TypeError: Cannot write property of null

Third time:

> qrc:/MyObject.qml:15: TypeError: Cannot write property of null
>
> qrc:/MyObject.qml:15: TypeError: Cannot write property of null
>
> qrc:/MyObject.qml:15: TypeError: Cannot write property of null

I'm wondering if the `replace` flag in the `push` method does actually `pop` (and therefore destroy) the object and all objects contained.

Comment: So what is your question? What are 2 `Loader`s you are talking about? What is `item`?

Comment: The questions are: "am I using StackView correcly?", "does replace actually pop objects before pushing the new one?". If you want to make transitions between objects you need two loaders: one with the current content and one with the new one, then they will swap. item is just a placeholder to show the code, it's the id of the component (obj1, etc...)

Comment: Yo might want to look at the `SwipeView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html

> There are three primary navigation operations in StackView: push(), pop(), and replace (replace by specifying argument replace to push()). These correspond to classic stack operations where "push" adds an item to the top of a stack, "pop" removes the top item from the stack, and **"replace" is like a pop followed by a push**, in that it replaces the topmost item on the stack with a new item

I think your problem might be related to this:

[QML StackView: Item Destroyed on pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961827/qml-stackview-item-destroyed-on-pop)

(use Item instead of Component)

Comment: yeah, you're right. In these days I was trying to change my code as in that thread and I solved.